# Kendo UI Datasource onRequestEnd e.response.Data not found

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui

i'm trying to intercept datetime value in kendo datasource to adjust UTC time offset but i can't find the e.response.Data property

code

```
var interceptDate = []; // List of intercept member
var onRequestEnd = function (e) {
                        setIntercept(e); // another function to fill interceptDate from schema
                        if (e.response.Data && e.response.Data.length) {
                            var rowsData = e.response.Data;
                            if (interceptDate.length > 0) {
                                if (this.group().length && e.type == "read") {
                                    for (var i = 0; i < rowsData.length; i++) {
                                        var gr = rowsData[i];
                                        for (var j = 0; j < interceptDate.length; j++) {
                                            if (gr.Member == interceptDate[j]) {
                                                gr.Key = gr.Key.replace(/\d+/,
                                                    function (n) { return parseInt(n) + offsetMiliseconds; }
                                                );
                                            }
                                            addOffset(gr.Items);
                                        }
                                    }
                                } else {
                                    addOffset(rowsData);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    };
```

in chrome devtools the e.response look like

```
_defaultPrevented: false
isDefaultPrevented: function (){return this._defaultPrevented===!0}
preventDefault: function (){this._defaultPrevented=!0}
response: Object
odata.count: "4"
odata.metadata: "http://localhost:7000/odata/$metadata#DateIntercept"
value: Array[4]
0: Object
1: Object
2: Object
3: Object
length: 4
__proto__: Array[0]
__proto__: Object
sender: lt.extend.init
type: "read"
__proto__: Object
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to modify the returned data, you should use the [parse](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource#configuration-schema.parse) callback in the dataSource's schema.  Leaving out irrelevant stuff it would look something like:

```
new kendo.ui.Grid({
    dataSource: new kendo.data.DataSource({
        schema: {
            parse: function (results) {
                for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
                    // MODIFY RESULTS HERE.  FOR EXAMPLE
                    results[i].someField = results[i].someField + " Hello World";
                }
                return results;
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: i'am trying to implement this : [sample code](http://www.telerik.com/support/code-library/using-utc-time-on-both-client-and-server-sides),.. i'm  using odata v3 services and get time offset 5 -7 hour each time creating new record